# CakePHP Model with Multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, cakephp, models

I have a model which makes use of a table however does not really represent the table. This model shall use this table and perform multiple joins with different models, say 5 other models.  Which is the best way to do this?  Would you define joins separately and then merge them into one join array as seen below? Is this the best approach ?

```
        $PlansJoin = array(
            "table" => "plans_master",
            "alias" => "Plan",
            "type" => "INNER",
            "conditions" => array(
                "Plan.plan_id = KpiReporter.plan_id"
            )
        );

        $BrandJoin = array(
            "table" => "brands",
            "alias" => "Brand",
            "type" => "INNER",
            "conditions" => array(
                "Brand.brand_id = Plan.brand_id",
                "OR" => array(
                    "Brand.brand_id" => $options["brand"],
                    "'all'" => $options["brand"]
                )
            )
        );

        $UserJoin = array(
            "table" => "users",
            "alias" => "User",
            "type" => "INNER",
            "conditions" => array(
                "User.user_id = KpiReporter.user_id"
            )
        );



       return $this->find("all", array(
                    "fields" => array_keys($this->virtualFields),
                    "joins" => $joins,
                    "group" => $group,
                    "conditions" => $conditions,
                    "order" => $order
        ));
```

Could associations be used for these complex queries ?

Comment: You could use bindModel for most of those joins. Brand may be one you have to keep as a join (try using conditions first), but the fewer joins the better I'd say. 

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#creating-and-destroying-associations-on-the-fly

Comment: What does this mean _I have a model which makes use of a table however does not really represent the table._? Are you trying to make a model based on complex query? That is whenever you access that model, you will always use those JOINs (complex or not)? If so, in MySQL, I would create a VIEW based on that complex SQL statement, then in CakePHP utilize the `$useTable` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use bindModel() method 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

or use containable behavior.. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

I've used both, and I found that containable is much more easier to implement.

Comment: Yes I am looking into containable behaviours. However this is an enterprise application and thus being maintainable is key. bindModel seems to be sort of a quickfix, whilst containable behavior looks more flexible.. might be mistaken though

Answer (score 0):

it will change your life, when you are using cakephp => http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

When you active this "behaviors" , in your query, juste chose your join with an array "contain"

like this :

```
return $this->find("all", array(
                    "fields" => array_keys($this->virtualFields),
                    "joins" => $joins,
                    "group" => $group,
                    "conditions" => $conditions,
                    "order" => $order,
                    "contain"=> array('NameOfLinkedModel')

        ));
```